# How to debug application with "minifyEnabled true" and disable MultiDexApplication in release mode

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When `build.gradle` has lines:

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        minifyEnabled true
    }
```

we cannot debug an application. A solution is to write:

```
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug{
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }

...
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

And in MyApplication file write:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

But when we turn to release mode the application still inherits from `MultiDexApplication`. So there can be some compatibility problems with old devices. Is there a way, for instance, in Gradle, to avoid `MultiDexApplication` in release mode and retain it only in debug mode? I read https://xrubio.com/2016/10/disabling-removing-code-on-release-builds/ but unsure if it can help.

Comment: "Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively supports loading multiple DEX files from APK files" ...
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex ... `com.android.support:multidex` is only required when targeting "old devices" (< API level 21).

Comment: @MartinZeitler, thanks, you are right, but I aim to target devices from API level 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use [build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants). Basically, this lets you specify code that is only included in either the debug or release versions of your app. You do this by putting the code you only want in one version in `src/debug` or `src/release` instead of `src/main`. Exactly what code goes where is up to you. You have a couple of options here.

**1.** You could have two copies of `MyApplication`, one extending `MultiDexApplication` in `src/debug` and the other extending the base `Application` class in `src/release`. This way, the multi-dex code is only included in the debug build, not the release build. You still specify your application class in `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. This option is best if you don't have anything else in your Application class.

**2.** If your application class has significant code in it beyond multi-dex, it may be easier to have a base abstract class that contains everything else, and extend it in `src/debug` and `src/main`, adding the following to your debug version (as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)):

```
public class MyApplication extends BaseApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

**3.** The third option is to actually declare different Application classes in debug vs. release. This can be done by having that declaration in `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and the release equivalent. Then, you can do whatever you want, including not declaring an application class in one version. This works well if you have several different parts in your class that are different between release and debug, or don't need an application class in one of them.

Comment: Thanks! A brilliant answer! I will try it later.

Comment: Great, let me know if questions arise that could help improve this answer! I feel this is a pretty common problem people encounter, and would like to polish this one up.